# Need to Draw a rectangle in counter area with android opencv

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

i Need to Draw a rectangle in counter area with android opencv
here is my code but i'm having error in Core.rectangle part or is there any easy way to draw it?

```
MatOfPoint2f         approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();  
List<Rect> ListOfRect = new ArrayList<Rect>();
for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
   MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(i).toArray() );
   double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true)*0.02;
   Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);
   MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() ); 
   Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);

   //error part
   Core.rectangle(img, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height), new Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ),0,8, 0);      
}

error: The method rectangle(org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Scalar, int) in the type Core is not applicable for the arguments (org.opencv.core.Mat, android.graphics.Point, android.graphics.Point, org.opencv.core.Scalar, int)
```

Answer (score 2):

the way i resolved this issue was using Imgproc.rectangle instead of Core.rectangle. What i learnt was Core.rectangle was not included in version 3 which had to be replaced with the Imgproc class. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message states, the argument types do not match. You are passing `android.graphics.Point` instances, but `Core.rectangle()` expects objects of type `org.opencv.core.Point`.

To work around this issue, you can use methods on `Rect` to get the point locations you desire:

```
Core.rectangle(img, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255),0, 8, 0);
```

Comment: good explanation.got it. can you please explane what is tl() and br()?

Comment: They are the top-left and bottom-right corners of the rectangle. I suggest you also read the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/). It's a little spotty for Java, but it can help you get a better handle on things.